# Show circular progress indicator, async task

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, progress-indicator

I am trying to show a circular progress indicator, while I run an async task. The async task is triggered by a button click and is also directing the user to a new page. The code looks like this:

```
child: GestureDetector(
   onTap: () async{

     //some async task that takes a few seconds

     Navigator.push( ...
}
```

I want the user, when he clicks the button to first see a **circular progress indicator** and when the task is complete he should be directed to another screen. But I have no idea how to show him this progress indicator.
Thanks for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I made a little simulation of what you want:

Check the code below:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  // boolean variable to decide when to show progress indicator
  bool showProgress = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () async {
            // set the progress indicator to true so it will be visible
            setState(() {
              showProgress = true;
            });
            // perform asynchronous task here
            await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), null);

            setState(() {
              // set the progress indicator to true so it would not be visible
              showProgress = false;
              // navigate to your desired page
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnotherScreen()));
            });
          },
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Your widgets can stay here',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Center(
                  // use ternary operator to decide when to show progress indicator
                  child: showProgress
                      ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                      : Text('Tap me'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check output below:

[Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvWxt.jpg)

NOTE: For the sake of simplicity(the example above was used). To avoid calling `setState` multiple times. You can use a state management technique like [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) or [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and maybe decide to make use of a service locator for injection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library https://pub.dev/packages/simpleprogressdialog

> Create an object of ProgressDialog

`ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context: context, barrierDismissible: false);`

Then invoke `showMaterial` before your async task

```
progressDialog.showMaterial(layout: MaterialProgressDialogLayout.overlayWithCircularProgressIndicator);
```

Then after the async task, dismiss the dialog.

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```